# how to you window.mediaQuery matches in typescript

Tags: typescript, media-queries

i have table with many columns and i want to hide based on browser width so i try to use window.matchMedia("(max-width:700)").matches , window.media("(max-width:500)").matches etc.. in typescript but i cant get media listener . please find the code

```
for(let i : number =0 ; i< this.col.length; i++){
let media,
media = window.matchMedia(col[i].minWidth);
this.mcol.push(col[i])
this.mediaQueryUpdate(media)
media.addEventLister(mediaQueryUpdate)

}

public medaiQueryUpdate(e:any){
if(window.matchMedia(e.target.media).match){ // did not get target e , error thrown as e does not found
for(let c: number =0 ; c< this.mcol.length; c++){
   if(window.matchMedia(e.target.media) == this.mcol[c].minWidth ){
 // did nto get target from e 
mcol[c].hide=  true;
}
 }
}
```

Comment: any reason why you are not using css to do this?

Comment: we dont know max-width/min-width it gets dynamically

Comment: you can still set the display property to none in css regardless..

Answer (score 4):

Use type MediaQueryList

```
isSmallMobileDevice: MediaQueryList = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 599px)")
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to you window.mediaQuery matches in typescript

Quickest solution, just use an assertion:

```
if ((window.matchMedia(e.target.media) as any).match) {
```

## More

- Assertions : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html
- Add types to lib.d.ts : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html